# Given an integer number n return all combinations m of given length M for which m_1+m_2+m_3+.....m_m = n

Tags: recursion, combinations, python-itertools, combinatorics

I am trying to solve an old problem I had but I can't find an algorithm (I feel like it is recursive) or ideally an itertools solution.

Given an integer number n return all combinations m of given length M for which m_1+m_2+m_3+.....m_m = n

for example: if n=2 και M=3 i need to get the lists m: [2,0,0],[0,2,0],[0,0,2],[1,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,1] but for arbitrary n and M.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that this admits a recursive solution. Indeed, say we want `f(n,M)` to return a list of tuples of `M` elements adding up to `n`. It shouldn't be hard to convince yourself that, for any nonnegative `k<=n`, every tuple in `f(n-k,M-1)` can be turned into a tuple from `f(n,M)` by simply adding a `k` term (and vise versa, every tuple in `f(n,M)` with a `k` term will yield a tuple from `f(n-k,M-1)` if this term is removed). With this in mind:

```
def f(n,M):
    if M==1:
        return [(n,)]
    sequences = []
    for k in range(n+1):
        for sequence in f(n-k,M-1):
            sequences.append((k,)+sequence)
    return sequences
```

Note the base case here - if `M==1`, there is only one possible sequence. You might also want to handle `M==0`, which should return `[tuple()]` if `n==0` and `[]` otherwise.

It would be best to do this as a generator, since you can generate these sequences on the fly:

```
def f(n,M):
    if M==1:
        yield [(n,)]
    else:
        for k in range(n+1):
            yield from map(lambda sequence: (k,)+sequence, f(n-k, M-1))
```

I don't believe that itertools can help with this in any obvious way - `combinations` can certainly help generate all possible `M`-tuples so we can later only keep those that add up to `n`, but this would quickly become unacceptably slow. Generating valid tuples directly requires having some awareness of what's going on "arithmetically" while creating these tuples, which, to my understanding, is not something itertools is built to do.